# Limitations of the downloadable imdb data

Tags: mysql, text-extraction, imdb

I am importing imdb into MySQL. The description of the downloadable plain-text imdb data files says that they contain a **subset** of the imdb data. Does anyone know what the limitations of the (scope of the) downloadable data are? For example, are there movies that are not included in the downloadable data?

Answer (score 3):

In the **plain text data files** you will not find information that were added later, once IMDb became a company.

The main limitation, is the fact that you will not have the **imdbIDs** (the IDs used to identify movies, persons, characters and companies), so you can't easily match the information in the plain text data files with the ones on the web site.

Besides this, notable **missing categories of data** are: the short plot on the main page, awards, external reviews, parents guide, synopsis, faqs, news.

Obviously, all the message boards, posters and so on are missing.

You can do some comparison of your data with their stats: http://www.imdb.com/stats , but their way to categorize movies on the web site may differ from the one you find in the file, so it's not an easy comparison.

A notable exception, strictly talking about the amount of data, is that "**in development**" titles are not included in the files, as far as I know (while a movie is in the early stages of production, information are only available to subscribers of IMDb PRO).